# angular.js(1): img tag using ng-src can't retrieve AWS image from url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting an image url returned to me on my node server while using the Lob printing API.

It renders on the page when I hardcode the URL in the angular template file like so:

```
<img ng-src="<imageurl>"></img>
```

But when I use it dynamically, I get an error in console and no image:

```
GET <imageurl> 404 (Not Found)
```

My HTML

```
<img ng-src="{{data.image.url}}"></img>
```

If I hardcode something in the controller like:

```
 $scope.data.image.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(<image url>)
```

then it works.

But if I don't hardcode the returned image link, and just dynamically render the string, even if I sanitize it, like so...

```
$scope.data.image.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(returnedData.url)
```

I get the 404 on the page.

It also doesn't work with: trustAsUrl, setting trustAsUrl or trustAsResourceUrl as a filter, trying to render through src and not ng-src, any of it.

Inspecting the rendered empty image box shows me that the ng-src attribute and the src attribute appear to have the correct url in them.

Comment: when you inspect the rendered element what does the "src" attribute contain? is it a fully formed URI?

Comment: Yeah, with both ng-src and src attributes filled out with the same

Comment: what version of angular? Ill setup a fiddle with a working example for you. I suspect you may have a permissions issue with your image in S3???

Comment: 1.6.1 ---It's not really my image, it's returned to me through a 3rd party api

Comment: Working Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jherter/kz4eyeq5/4/ hope this helps =)

Comment: yeah, the problem is that the ng-src appears to be resolving correctly, but no image displays